# How to reference a method within class as a callback to a custom function in PHP?

Tags: php

I have some code that executes an anonymous function that, which looks something like this

```php
class A
{
    public static function foo(callable $callback)
    {
        $callback('Foo executed.');
    }
}

class B
{
    public function execute()
    {
        A::foo(function ($phrase) {
            echo $phrase;
        });
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->execute();  // "Foo executed."
```

but instead of doing it that way, I want to move the anonymous function to be a class method and then pass that method as the parameter.

The problem is that I am not sure how or if it's even possible to reference the class method in this manner when doing it with a *custom* method.

Basically, I want to be able to reference the function without calling it, similar to how you can do `array_map('strtoupper', $words)` with native PHP functions, referencing the native `strtoupper` method instead of doing `function ($w) { return strtoupper($w); }`.

Here is what I would prefer to do:

```php
class A
{
    public static function foo(callable $callback)
    {
        $callback('Foo executed');
    }
}

class B
{
    public function execute()
    {
        A::foo('speak');  // <- This is obviously wrong because we are passing a string and not a callable
    }

    public function speak($phrase)
    {
        echo $phrase;
    }
}
```

I've also tried doing, but they result in the respective errors:

- `static::speak` results in `Undefined class constant 'speak'`
- `$this::speak` results in `Undefined class constant 'speak'`
- `self::speak` results in `Undefined class constant 'speak'`
- `$this->speak` results in `Undefined property: B::$speak`
- `$this->speak()` results in `Too few arguments to function B::speak(), 0 passed ...`

How can I achieve this and is it even achievable in PHP?

Comment: Btw, my solution ended up being `A::(\Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'speak']))` because the type-hint  was actually of type `Closure` in my case (Closure is stricter). For a normal `callable` type, you can simply pass `[$this, 'speak']` instead. I used the link to the duplicate question which led me to the solution I needed.